# Получение формы после ajax запроса в Symfony3

Tags: ajax, form, symfony, serialize, symfony3

Целый день пытаюсь, не могу получить поля после сериализации формы в symfony3. Вывод ошибок формы показал, что она не получила значения полей.

Код формы:

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'action': '/ajax_garden_save/'~garden.vars.value.id~'' } }) }}
    {{  form_widget(garden.id, { 'attr': { 'readonly' : 'readonly' } }) }}
    <td class="table-data">{{ key + 1 }}</td>
    <td class="form-group">{{ form_widget(garden.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'table-inputs', 'readonly' : 'readonly' } }) }}</td>
    <td class="form-group">{{ form_widget(garden.rows, { 'attr': {'class': 'table-inputs', 'readonly' : 'readonly' } }) }}</td>
     <td>
        <button type="button" id='{{ garden.vars.value.id }}' class="btn btn-default btn-icon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-original-title="Edit"></button>
        <a role="button" id='{{ garden.vars.value.id }}' data-toggle="modal" href="#small_modal" class="btn btn-default btn-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-original-title="Delete"></a>
     </td>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Код jQuery:

```
/* Events after clicking on save button */
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).attr("disabled", true);

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        type: $(this).attr("method"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Форма не проходит валидацию. Код контроллера:

```
public function ajaxSaveAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $garden = $em->getRepository('FarmBundle:Garden')->find($id);
        $form = $this->createForm('Valmrnk\FarmBundle\Form\GardenType', $garden);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            return new JsonResponse('Success', 200);
        } else {
            $jsonResponse = new JsonResponse();
            $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
            $form = $serializer->serialize($form, 'json');
            $data = array(
                'success' => false,
                'errorList' => $form
            );

            $jsonResponse->setData($data);

            return $jsonResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Сделал еще в контроллере var_dump, вот что он возвращает:

```
object(FarmBundle\Entity\Garden)#428 (4) {
    ["id":"FarmBundle\Entity\Garden":private] => int(2)
    ["name":"FarmBundle\Entity\Garden":private] => string(8) "Garden 1"
    ["rows":"FarmBundle\Entity\Garden":private] => int(1)
    ["createdAt":"FarmBundle\Entity\Garden":private]=>
        object(DateTime)#425 (3) {
            ["date"] => string(26) "2016-06-28 00:00:00.000000"
            ["timezone_type"] => int(3)
            ["timezone"] => string(3) "UTC"
        }
}
```

Вот как выглядит request:

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)#8 (21) {
    ["attributes"]=>
        object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#11 (1) {
            ["parameters":protected]=> array(4) {
                ["_controller"]=> string(54) "FarmBundle\Controller\GardenController::ajaxSaveAction"
                ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
                ["_route"]=> string(16) "ajax_garden_save"
                ["_route_params"]=> array(1) {
                    ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
                }
             }
         }
         ["request"]=>     object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag)#9 (1) {
             ["parameters":protected]=> array(1) {
                 ["gardens"]=>array(2) {
                     ["gardens"]=> array(1) {
                         [0]=>array(3) {
                             ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
                             ["name"]=> string(19) "Garden<h1>Test</h1>"
                             ["rows"]=> string(3) "111"
                          } 
                      }
                   }

                   ["_token"]=> string(43) "LV0i4C92bn8yip4jLEFMoAK9tfcZzMKexexrRkJDQoU"
              }
         }
}
```

Comment: а где input  поля в форме,ведь $(this).serialize() это ихние value в сериализованном виде (name=Vaysa&mail=test@tst.com),что за td ,вы пытаетесь их значение получить чтоли ? 
{{ form_row(form.name) }} 
{{ form_row(form.dueDate) }} 
по моему это input поля генерирует
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Да, вы правы,  {{ form_row(form.name) }} генерирует простые поля input. А элементы td, потому что формы и поля хранятся внутри таблицы. Один ряд tr - одна форма, столбец td - один из input.

Comment: сделайте следующее
$("form").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log($(this).serialize());
});

если выведет строку со значениями input ,
тогда надо посмотреть какие правила валидации написано для каждого input

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Если сделать .serialize выводит: gardens%5Bgardens%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=2&gardens%5Bgardens%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=Garden+1&gardens%5Bgardens%5D%5B0%5D%5Brows%5D=1&gardens%5B_token%5D=9O3ebUu9m4MEGISgCXnU7ok7ZZDSz2Z-d53AdnXgFZQ  . Если .serilizeArray():  то выводит массив обьектов, элементами которого являются поля со значениями. Значит данные получает.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста как выглядит массив данных в request? Может быть в нем дело..

Comment: @AmsTaFFix дополнил вопрос, проблему так и не решил( У меня есть две формы GardenType и GardensType(коллекция GardenType). Вывожу во view как коллекцию форм, пробовал создать форму обоих типов, при GardenType все хорошо, при GardensType Ошибка, значит проблема не в этом. И form->getData() выводит поля и значения( Не могу понять в чем проблема уже третий день...

Comment: Вы сказали, что при использовании типа GardenType все работает нормально, а можете ли скинуть var_dump реквеста при передаче такой формы?

Comment: @AmsTaFFix оказалось пробелема была в отсутствии метода setId()  в модели.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение путем превращения ajax запроса в обыкновенный post-запрос. Как оказалось, проблема в том, что в моей сущности Entity, не было метода setId().

```
<?php

namespace FarmBundle\Entity;

class Garden
{

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```